# MetaMask does not let me send transactions on private network

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, metamask, json-rpc, pow

Metamask lets me deploy contracts on my private network and but it does not let me send transactions.
Its real network running on a few nodes with PoW, only thing different is that minimum gas fee is changed from 21k to 11k.
Its lastest geth node with working rpc and synced.

Funny thing is that wallet I built works with the network without any problems :)
On metamask phone it works too!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try going into settings > advanced > Reset Account

this will reset your transactions and nonce I know sometimes that happens when using testnets.

Hope it helps[image]

Comment: I did it a couple of times but its still not working, thanks for something :)

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is maybe you entered the network info wrong by accident on metamask extenstion? If it's working on mobile but not your desktop.